# ASp.net core IActionResult csv encoding problem

Tags: c#, excel, csv, encoding, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a problem when trying to save a csv file though an IActionResult. Special characters like åøæ will not be shown properly when opening the csv file. I have tried a lot of different approaches, but nothing seems to work. My latest attempt was trying to use the CsvHelper library but doesn’t seem to work neither. Here is my latest attempt.

```
        byte[] result;
        await using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        await using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, new UTF8Encoding(true)))
        {
            var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            csvWriter.Configuration.Delimiter = ";";
            await csvWriter.WriteRecordsAsync(data);
            await streamWriter.FlushAsync();
            result = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }

        return new FileStreamResult(new MemoryStream(result), "text/csv")
        { FileDownloadName = $"data.csv" };
```

I hobe someone can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Any update? Does my reply has helped you?

Comment: I found the problem wasn't my ActionResult, but was a ajax call my colleague made. It worked changing the window.location.href directly to my actionresult. But this creates timeouts, because it is a slow call.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this issue is related with Excel not asp.net core application. We could set the download file format to use `utf-8`, but excel doesn't open it with right format.

You could open your csv file and find it shows as below:

[image]

But excel shows like this:

[image]

To force excel to show the special character, you should follow below steps:

1.Open Excel and new a empty excel

2.Import the data using Data-->Import External Data --> Import Data

3.Select the file type of "csv" and browse to your file

4.In the import wizard change the File_Origin to "65001 UTF" (or choose correct language character identifier)

5.Change the Delimiter to comma

6.Select where to import to and Finish

Generate csv codes:

```
          List<Student> students = new List<Student>
{
    new Student { Id = 1, FirstName = "éåæÉà;some other value", LastName = "Kanjilal" },
    new Student { Id = 2, FirstName = "Steve", LastName = "Smith" },
    new Student { Id = 3, FirstName = "Anand", LastName = "Narayaswamy"}
};
            try
            {
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                stringBuilder.AppendLine("Id,FirstName,LastName");
                foreach (var student in students)
                {
                    stringBuilder.AppendLine($"{student.Id},  { student.FirstName},{ student.LastName}");
                }
                return File(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes
                (stringBuilder.ToString()), "text/csv;charset=utf-8", "student.csv");
            }
            catch
            {
                return Error();
            }
```